# Windows 7 boot failure after Ubuntu 14.04 installation

Tags: 14.04, boot, windows-7

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Acer netbook a week or two ago which ran Windows 7 before the Ubuntu installation. I know that my question isn't the first of it's kind but I'm not the most seasoned when it comes to Ubuntu, or Windows for that matter, installation or repair. From what I can tell I must have either partitioned my HDD incorrectly or installed Ubuntu or a part there of in a way that blocks grub from Windows 7. I have already attempted to repair grub using boot-repair (through Grub Customizer) and even though the repair via the repair report was successful I still can not boot Windows 7. 
Here is the boot-repair report itself 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/9553822/
I will keep reading through the already answered questions but for now any advice or help would be appreciated.
Thank you, 
Eli

Answer (score 0):

I don't claim to be expert interpreting the boot-repair reports, but I don't see a surviving windows partition, so I honestly don't think you have windows anymore.  If it helps I can tell you a lot of things to make you feel better about that, and I can offer significant assistance helping you to set up WINE such that you will actually be able to run windows software under ubuntu BETTER than it ever ran under windows.

Now, just in case I misread that boot-repair report, please open the Ubuntu utility known as "disk utility" to verify the windows partition still exists.  If it does, it ought to be possible to fix it with boot repair, although personally I disliked the version of boot repair you install on the drive you are trying to fix.  I recommend that which runs from a live boot CD, as that's the only type which has worked for me.

Personally I suspect that as many such complaints I've read, you accidentally wiped out your windows partition and there's no getting it back, short of a restore from a full backup.

Comment: Are there any other alternatives to running from a live CD? I'm working on a netbook without a CD/DVD drive. I would assume a USB would be my next best bet?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use a utility such as unetbootin (not included, you need to install the downloaded ISO from the ubuntu software center) to install the cd image onto a flash drive.  There it will mimick the CDROM as though you have one.

Comment: Alright I'll give that a shot, thanks for your help.

Comment: You've not said if you opened disk utility and found anything that resembles a windows partition.  Should I assume your eagerness to use an externally booted boot-repair medium means you found the partition?